# Related Products - What am I doing wrong? (they're not showing up in sidebar!)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have several products in my store.  I have 4 products specifically that I have assigned "Related Products" to.  When I load my store, and add or view products, the Related Products box is not showing up anywhere on any of the pages.

http://moscowballet.tellusdev.com/nutcrackers/ - Add a product and click continue shopping.  There should be the Related Products box under the My Cart box, but it's not :-(

Also, the cross sells and upsells functions are not working either I notice, even though I have all of them assigned properly in the product settings.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Have you tried to flush cache and rebuild all indices? Also, I see you use some custom theme. Are you sure these blocks exist in this theme?

Comment: Yes, we've cleared all the cache settings more than 100 times since this started happening.

It's not a custom them, it's the Modern theme from basic Magento CE install.  The only major thing I've done is changed some CSS, changed the float on the main and 2nd column to switch their position on the pages.  Any I remove the code for the Compare module.

Comment: Seems like you fixed it, I see now cross sells or up sells in the left column on my cart page.

Comment: Yes, it was an Index Management issue that I never would have thought to explore, since I normally only have to deal with cache management.  Thanks for your time though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that we have run into as well with our store.  Try this:

Go into catalog > manage products

and select one of the products that is not working correctly.  Then go to it's

Inventory > manage stock.  Try clicking the "Use Config Settings" until it is selected.  Save the edits and view your product page.

On our store view this was all that was necessary to fix the problem.  Somewhat unnerving considering the fact that if the box was already checked we simply had to uncheck and check it again (no effective change at all) and the related products would show up...

EDIT (for others viewing post):

System -> Index Management - Reindex Data worked for OP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the solution didn't work for me :-(

I toggled the setting to un-checked, saved the product, then checked it again, then refreshed my cache (all of them), and I am still not seeing anything show up in the side bar.

Comment: Hmm..well have you tried @Zyava 's suggestions above?  We haven't figured out a long term solution for our problem so its probably a good thing you aren't experiencing the 'checkbox syndrome'

Comment: Try...System -> Index Management - Reindex Data

Comment: thepristinedesign - YOU ARE BRILLIANT!  That worked!  Didn't think I had Index Management enabled on this cart, but evidently I did.  Never would have though to look there since most issues are the Cache Management side.  THANK YOU so much!!!

Comment: No problem.  If the solution worked for you I'd appreciate a +1 or accepted answer (its a numerical thankyou on stackoverflow) :)

Comment: I think I did it right, and thank you again!!!